# How to browse server-side files in django with FileField?

Tags: python, django

As in question, i have form with

```
file = forms.FileFIeld(widget = forms.FIleInput())
```

but this allows me to browse files on clients computer. I would like to show me my own server-side files. I am fully aware of security risks. This is my personal project and won't be used by anyone else (just in case anyone would shout at me). It doesn't have to be just the same mechanism. I only want to obtain this name from form. Nothing shall be uploaded or downloaded.

This will work as file selecting for another server app.

If it isn't possible to browse whole computer, how can I specify directories where I can store files for further browsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a system to access files on your computer remotely, you can do it using ftp or ssh.

If you need to access files in a particular directory you can put them in the `static` part of django and have [django serve you static content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/). This is however not the intended design for django and you might as well serve files of a http server with Apache.

If you are looking to build a google docs/dropbox kind of web service, then django can help you as a web framework. However you would need to run some kind of local indexing and add all file metadata indexes to your database using something like [PyLucene](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/) and then upload the same files to a downloadable [path online](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or on your `static` serve folder. This is not a Django problem per se.

Comment: I have application on this server and I want it to perform some tasks on files. Django is only a GUI for this operation. So all I want to do is to let me select file, and pass its name to another module. It can't be ssh because this GUI servers other not related things with this project.

Comment: And you need to do this on the web? Web browsers are not very good at accessing local file content. Try using PyQt or EPD suite for building a desktop app.

Comment: I would love to use something else, but whole project is already in Django and file selecting is the only thing missing :) And also it has to be web app to provide remote access.

Comment: Well then write a script that copies or symlinks files you need to the `static` folder of your web app and at the same time populates the database with path and filename and other data you might need. Then just list them, you don't need a widget or anything. They can be clicked and download if the headers are correct.

Comment: sshfs does the job. 1. create a local directory client-side (eg /home/remote). 2. connect to server '$sshfs -o /path/to/ssh_keys.pem user@server_IP:/the/serverpath/you/want/to/browse /home/remote'. 3. browse /home/remote using any browser. 4. To disconnect '$fusermount -u /home/remote'

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the stored files through your model.

Suppose your model is declared like this

```
import os
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    doc_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

You can get the file just like any other field

```
names = []
# To browse your saved file, get the containing models
documents = Document.objects.all()
for doc in documents:
    # This is how you get the URL of the file field
    url = doc.doc_file.url
    # If you need the path of the stored file (in the server)
    doc_path = doc.doc_file.path
    # get name and size of the file
    name, size = doc.doc_file.name.split(os.path.sep)[-1], doc.doc_file.size
    names.append(name)
#process your file names
...
```

Then you just go process the URL, for example, display it to your users.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I asked in a bad way. I only want to browse files with a dialog box like I can browse clients files. I don't want to upload/download anything. Only the name of the file.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I still don't understand your question. I've updated my answer, take a look at the last line. It should get you the name of the file.

Comment: If you want to be able to browser ANY files contained within your server, @Pratik already give the answer.